# Can SQL Server Express (or any version) run on RPi?

Tags: sql-server, windows, raspberry-pi3

I note that the full version of Windows 10 can be run on a RPI 3.

I wondered whether SQL Server Express (or any other edition) is available for the ARM version of Windows. I can’t see it anywhere so I suspect the answer is ‘no’ but want to check I have my missed a trick anywhere.

Effectively I am testing out working with a large SQL Server database. I don’t want my test code to touch the actual site, so my plan was to run a minimal example with some test records locally on my desk. I have an old Atom-based machine I can use - but the RPi is a much more convenient in terms of having a ‘portable’ demo server.

I am aware any such setup will perform awfully - performance not an issue for the demo.

Comment: The actual question is "is there a SQL Server version for *ARM*"? And I'd guess no. There is an embedded version that does target ARM, SQL Server Compact, that may or may not run on Windows IoT. It was made primarily for Windows Embedded and Windows Phone

Comment: No ARM version - according to the [Operating Systems requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#TOP_Principal) SQL Server is only supported on Windows 10 IoT *Enterprise*, essentially a Windows 10 Enterprise version with different licensing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here :

- Is there a SQL Server version that runs on ARM?

According to the [Operating System requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#TOP_Principal) no. SQL Server is only available for [Windows IoT *Enterprise*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot-enterprise), essentially a Windows 10 Enterprise version with special licensing. It's the evolution of Windows Embedded and only meant for OEMs that produce 1000s of devices.

And the real question

- I don’t want my test code to touch the actual site, so my plan was to run a minimal example

In that case you can use Windows 10 containers, a VM or a managed cloud version of SQL Server. SQL Server docker images are available for the [Express](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/) and [Developer](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer/) edition.

Answer (score 0):

No, in contrast with .net, powershell and other initiatives, up to this point there is no ARM version of SQL Server. And by knowing how existing version was ported, we hardly can expect that it will appear soon on this platform.

Comment: SQL Server Compact targets ARM. I'm not sure how well it will run on Windows IoT though

Comment: Good point, however it is deprecated, very much different from regular versions and hardly will ever run on linux..